# Finding Only HTML Nodes Whose Attributes Match Exactly

Tags: python, xpath, selenium, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm working through a Selenium test where I want to assert a particular HTML node is an exact match as far as what attributes are present and their values (order is unimportant) and also that no other attributes are present. For example given the following fragment:

`<input name="test" value="something"/>`

I am trying to come up with the a good way of asserting its presence in the HTML output, such that the following (*arbitrary*) examples would **not match:**

- `<input name="test" value="something" onlick="doSomething()"/>`
- `<input name="test" value="something" maxlength="75"/>`
- `<input name="test" value="something" extraneous="a" unwanted="b"/>`

I believe I can write an XPath statement as follows to find all of these, for example:

`//input[value='something' and @name='test']`

But, I haven't figured out how to write in such a way that it excludes not exact matches in a generalize fashion. Note, it doesn't have to be an XPath solution, but that struck me as the most likely elegant possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about testing that the `value` and `name` attributes are present, and that the total number of attributes is exactly 2:

```
//input[@value='something' and @name='test' and count(attribute::*)=2]
```

Comment: Attribute counting is a good idea. I should have thought of this.

Comment: +1 concise and reliable. Perhaps you can use abbreviated syntax `//input[@value='something' and @name='test' and count(@*)=2]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bent upon XPath, you could also employ CSS locators. Here's a snippet to count the number of elements registering an exact CSS match -

```
private int getCSSCount(String aCSSLocator){ 
        String jsScript = "var cssMatches = eval_css(\"%s\", window.document);cssMatches.length;"; 
        return Integer.parseInt(selenium.getEval(String.format(jsScript, aCSSLocator))); 
    }
```

Not sure about how to exclude attributes, but additional attributes can be specified as-

```
int count = getCSSCount("input[name=test][maxlength=75][...]");
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Is this link the original inspiration? http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/

Comment: yep - use it all the time - great validation piece

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude unexpected attributes with XPath.

So you must find a safer way to locate elements you want. Things that you should consider:

1. In a `form`, each `input` should have a distinct name. The same is true for the `form` itself. So you can try `//form[@name='...']/input[@name='...']`
2. Add a class to the fields that you care about. Classes don't have be mentioned in any stylesheet. In fact, I used this for form field validation by using classes like `decimal number` or `alpha number`